# Polyfill for Object.create and browser support code

Tags: javascript, browser

I've these lines of code used as Javascript Polyfill to support oldest browser to understand Object.create but really don't know how the code
works.

```js
// polyfill
if (!Object.create) {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      throw new Error('Object.create implementation'
      + ' only accepts the first parameter.');
    }
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
  };
}
```

Comment: It works by creating a function, settings it's prototype to the passed in object, and return a new instance of that function. It's not a very good polyfill, in fact in my opition it's horrible, and you should use the [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) that actually returns a new object, and not a function instance

Comment: have a look at MDNs introduction to OOP with js. its not that complicated...

Comment: Thank you! @adeneo